# Using Laravel Fluent Query Builder, is there a way to search text based on 2 sub strings?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, fluent

Assuming I have strings in the database that looks like the following:

```
The quick brown fox 0 jumps over the lazy dog 0.
The quick brown fox 0 jumps over the lazy dog 1.
The quick brown fox 0 jumps over the lazy dog 2.
The quick brown fox 1 jumps over the lazy dog 0.
The quick brown fox 1 jumps over the lazy dog 1.
The quick brown fox 1 jumps over the lazy dog 2.
```

Is there a way to search for 2 sub strings, using Laravel Fluent Query Builder?

Say I'm looking for "fox 0" and "dog". The expected result would be:

```
The quick brown fox 0 jumps over the lazy dog 0.
The quick brown fox 0 jumps over the lazy dog 1.
The quick brown fox 0 jumps over the lazy dog 2.
```

This is what I currently have:

```
$searchStr = ["fox 0", "dog"];
$query->where('text', '=', $searchStr);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query condition that would give you those results is `where text like '%fox 0%' and text like '%dog%'`.

To translate into a fluent query would be:

```
$query->where('text', 'like', '%fox 0%')->where('text', 'like', '%dog%');
```

Or, keeping with your array:

```
$searchStr = ["fox 0", "dog"];
foreach($searchStr as $str) {
    $query->where('text', 'like', '%'.$str.'%');
}
```

Comment: Is there also a way to query for everything that has either "fox 0" or "dog" rather than requiring both?

Comment: @rotaercz You can use `orWhere()` to add or clauses.  `$query->where('text', 'like', '%fox 0%')->orWhere('text', 'like', '%dog%');`